# matlab plotting

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to draw a line in matlab. My scenario is like x=[-400:400] and 'y' should be of the same length but an irregular slope continuous line and finally I want to use plot command for plotting, say plot(x,y). Can anybody suggest how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't clear; if you know that you need to use `plot(x,y)`, then what is the problem?

Comment: It seems you've already answered your question.

Comment: I have to plot irregular line how will I choose the value of y

Comment: for x=-400 to -300 , y should be 150; ; for x= -300 to -200 , y should be from 150 to -200;; for x= -200 to 300, y should be from -200 to 200;; so on ..and I want to plot in one graph using plot(x,y)

Comment: @JustinOommen: That would be just `plot([-400 -300 -200 300], [150 150 -200 200])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you want to plot in steps of 1, then you have:

```
x1=-400:-300;
x2=-300:-200;
x3=-200:300;
x=[x1 x2 x3];
```

And then for y you will have:

```
y1=ones(1,length(x1));
y2=(-200-150)/(-200+300) (x2+300) + 150;
y3=(200+200)/(300+200) (x3+200) - 200;
y=[y1 y2 y3]
```

And then :

```
plot(x,y)
```